# PHP/JS - Accessing PHP variable from JS function Argument

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, html

.php

```
<?php
$timeArray = [355,400,609,1000];
$differentTimeArray = [1,45,622, 923];
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var i=0;
var eventArray = [];

function generateArray(arrayName){
   eventVideoArray = <?php echo json_encode(arrayName); ?>;
   var vid = document.getElementById('my_video');
   vid.currentTime = eventVideoArray[i];
}
</script>
<button onClick="javascript:generateArray(timeArray)"><button>
```

Currently I can get the function to generate the desired output by making generateArray have no arguments and replaing arrayName with $timeArray.

i.e. Working Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i=0;
var eventArray = [];

function generateArray(){
   eventVideoArray = <?php echo json_encode($timeArray); ?>;
   var vid = document.getElementById('my_video');
   vid.currentTime = eventVideoArray[i];
}
</script>
```

I want to use generate function to call on many different Time arrays, so getting JS to call directly from the php array would make coding much easier. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

[SOLVED]

Hi there,

Not sure about the comments regarding php not being able to run, I had a working example on my IIS just not quite flexible enough.

I solved the issue by rewriting the button in html. Now I can add new time arrays to video using the same function.

Thanks for the help.

```
<?php

    $timeArray = array();       
    $timeArray[] = 345.1;
    $timeArray[] = 789.1;
    $timeArray[] = 1002.1;
    $timeArray[] = 1200.12;

    $differentArray = array();
    $differentArray[] = 1500;
    $differentArray[] = 1700;

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 0;
var eventVideoArray = [];
function generateArray(arrayName){
    eventVideoArray = arrayName;
    var vid = document.getElementById('my_video');
    vid.currentTime = eventVideoArray[i];
}
</script>
<button id="goToTime" onClick="javascript:generateArray(<?php echo json_encode($timeArray); ?>)">timeArray</button>

<button id="goToTime" onClick="javascript:generateArray(<?php echo json_encode($$differentArray); ?>)">differentTimeArray</button>
```

Comment: A webserver will not parse PHP in a .html file...

Comment: @ChrisMaggs: it really depends on the configuration, webservers can be set to do so. As for the original question, you might need to insert those variables using an `echo`

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs on the server and JS runs on the client. You want the client to call the server for the values for the array you will need an Ajax call or print the values directly to the JS (as already done on your code).
Depending on the project making an Ajax call would be a bit too much to be done.

Comment: I will look into using AJAX for future projects, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

**A webserver will not parse PHP in a .html file...**

Either, generate your Javascript variable in your PHP file and declare it global..

Or, change your .html file extension to .php so that the PHP in it gets parsed by the webserver.